# Is there an equivalent of Common Lisp's push in Racket?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, racket

In Commons Lisp there is the command "push":

```
(define (push x a-list)
  (set-box! a-list (cons x (unbox a-list))))
```

It allows you to put elements first in a list, for instance.

Is there something like this in Racket?

I tried searching in the documentation, but couldn't find it.

The only thing I found was a [push](https://docs.racket-lang.org/forth/index.html?q=push#%28form._%28%28lib._forth%2Fmain..rkt%29._push%29%29) command in a package named Forth, build for stack-based calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push` is a macro. The expression `(push 10 *var*)` expands to `(setf *var* (cons 10 *var*))`. You can make a similar macro in racket/scheme:

```scm
(define-syntax push
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr var) 
     (set! var (cons expr var)))))

(define x '())
(push 10 x)
(push 20 x)
x ; ==> (20 10)
```

If you store your list in a box then you can also make it a function:

```scm
(define (push e box)
  (set-box! box (cons e (unbox box))))

(define x (box '()))
(push 10 x)
(push 20 x)
x ; ==> #&(20 10)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this might not work in all the places that common lisp's would. E.g., can you `(push 3 (car list-of-lists))` with this to add 3 to the first list in a list of lists?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Indeed. While this macro only will work with bindings CL version will work with everything that has a `setf` expander defined. The sky's the limit with CL :-)